# Tried to use "Archive Utility.app" today. The app is gone

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

A attempted to unzip a file using "Archive Utility.app" from the context menu of the file. I got the following message: +++++++
You can’t open the application “Archive Utility.app” because it’s in the Trash. To open this application, move it from the Trash +++++++

I looked into: System/Library/CoreServices/
and there's no “Archive Utility.app”

I looked into the Trash. It's not there either.

I have no idea why it's gone.

Does anyone has this experience before?

Comment: Is it in /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications? Apple moved it there (from CoreServices) a few versions ago.

Comment: Yes it is, Gordon. Thank you! Now, I know that it just didn't go away.

What's not funny is that - the utility is on the context menu of the zip file; yet I get the error message that I indicated.  

Got any idea what could have caused this error? and how to "fix" this?

Comment: I got macOS Sierra for quite sometime now and the "Archive Utility" when accessed from the context menu always work. It was a surprise to me that it failed to work today.

Comment: I run the app and used it to unzip a file. It worked. The background process could have died from whatever reason.  Thanks, Gordon!

Comment: @GordonDavisson I guess you should post your comment has an answer, since according to Loreto it worked